# How accurate are CSS's real-world units?

Tags: css

I'm beginning experiments with CSS' real-world units, specifically, `in` and `cm`, for purposes of printing.

Are these units based on how they will be displayed on-screen or how they will be printed by a printer? How accurate are these units?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to W3C, only `em`, `px` and `%` are recommended for screen, the others for print.

Therefore, in a print application, the `in` and `cm` measurements could be precisely accurate.

There is an excellent article on such applications here:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html

Comment: Relevant section [from W3C recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) and [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units). (“For low-dpi devices, the unit px represents the physical reference pixel and then other units are defined relative to it. Thus, 1in is defined as 96px which equals 72pt.”)