# How to follow HTML elements with CSS positioning?

Tags: html, css

With CSS positioning it is possible to put an element to a given coordinates. When coordinates and width of an element are known, it should be possible to compute coordinates of the element placed immediately next to it by adding block width, borders, margins etc. and use the new coordinates, e.g. for placing a bar of an arrow above the element.

Please see the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/s2pgX/) which make the idea obvious on a) table cells and b) floated divs with a kind of green pointer.

The table is positioned to left: 3cm, has border 0.25cm and border-spacing 0.3cm, so the first cell has left 3.55cm. Each cell is 1cm wide, has left and right border 0.15cm and border-spacing 0.3cm resulting in total width 1.60cm. The next cell starts at left 5.15cm, the next at 6.75cm etc. So I place divs to the computed coordinates with CSS properties

```
left: and top:
```

However, they do not match reliably/exactly the cells border. Contrary to my expectation, the green divs mismatch the table at various zooms both in Chrome and Firefox. Nor varying units of the CSS (cm, mm, px, pt, em, ex) helped.

I did both examples (table and float) in order to check that it is not table specific.

Is it expected to work? Did I do an mistake in estimating total cell width? I know about Canvas, I wonder why this does not work for me. I would appreciate any idea.

Comment: To go pixel perfect, I would use the `px` unit. It works great : http://jsfiddle.net/s2pgX/11/ (don't forget to have a nice CSS reset)

Comment: Unfortunately, even with `px` (e.g. @Brewal's linked code) the composition does not stay stable when zooming.

Comment: Zooming will never be perfect. Your screen "talk" in pixel, if you go for 110% zooming with px unit, you will have something like 1.1px. Which of course doesn't mean anything. If you go with percent, well, it is not better. I don't even talk about other units. This is all about approximations.

Comment: If so then it means that I misuse/abuse HTML+CSS and I cannot draw in this way. How does other scalable technologies (e.g. SVG) cope with this? [SVG example](http://jsfiddle.net/s2pgX/15/) follows the same idea of sequence of relative shifts (table cells in HTML, path with relative moves in SVG) followed by absolute coordinates (positioned divs in HTML, lines in SVG). It zooms perfectly.

Comment: This might be because it is made for this, but I can't help you more on this unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

From [W3C - em, px, pt, cm, in](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

> The so-called *absolute* units (cm, mm, in, pt and pc) mean the same in CSS as everywhere else. A length expressed in any of these will appear as exactly that size (**within the precision of the hardware and software**).

So, I would say some imprecision should be expected.

Answer (score 0):

if you try the firsts one adding by 1.55 instead, (in firefox), the second and first ones are good but the third one is bad in the right border, like the cell is bigger than it should. I would say after trying some stuff that is not really reliable.

http://jsfiddle.net/s2pgX/

```
<div class="pointer" style="left:  3.55cm; top: 3.2cm"></div>
<div class="pointer" style="left:  5.10cm; top: 3.2cm"></div>
<div class="pointer" style="left:  6.65cm; top: 3.2cm"></div>
```

Just FYI I tried the same code in opera, firefox and chrome and output is different in each one of them

Take a look here;

http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html

taken from;

[How accurate are CSS's real-world units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341808/how-accurate-are-csss-real-world-units)

> According to W3C, only em, px and % are recommended for screen, the
>   others for print.